# go get github.com/beego/bee Error install

Tags: go, beego

Using the advised install command

```
go get github.com/beego/bee
```

Results in the below error:

```
github.com/gadelkareem/delve/service/rpc2
go/src/github.com/gadelkareem/delve/service/rpc2/client.go:23:5: cannot use &RPCClient literal (type *RPCClient) as type service.Client in assignment:
    *RPCClient does not implement service.Client (wrong type for ExamineMemory method)
go/src/github.com/gadelkareem/delve/service/rpc2/server.go:96:52: not enough arguments in call to s.debugger.Restart
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome!  This question would attract more answers if it had a more descriptive title.  Also, it's good that you shared the error message, but ideally a question has some text describing the problem and the context.

Answer (score 3):

Refer from this [issue](https://github.com/beego/bee/issues/722), `export export GO111MODULE=on` before `go get`.